# Printing values using crystal reports using different database

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have developed an application for payroll management and I am facing trouble while using Crystal Reports for printing Pay Bills

Hi have two tables, first Pay_Head_Table with two fields Pay_head_Id and Pay_head_Name, like this
[image]

I have around 40 entries in this table, firstly I want to show all the values in Pay_Head_Name in the Page header of crystal reports, these all names will be treated as the columns.

Now in the second table, I have entries of all employees with their respective pay heads like this

[image]

Now, I want to print them in crystal reports like this

```
                 Basic Salary        Grade Pay         HRA          DA       ..............................    etc....

  Shish Pal      10330                 2800           2626        (0 or no value if there is no entry) 

  MK. Upa...     9750                  2800          2510         9036



  Total          20080                 5600          .............          .....................
```

I tried lot many ways but couldn't get the exact result, please help

Answer (score 0):

Create a group based on the employee id or name, place all the information in the group footer.
for the total place that in the report footer